# Can HEDS-5500 rotary encoder work with semicircular shaft?

Tags: encoder, rotary

Does anybody know if [HEDS-5500 rotary encoder](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/678/V02-1046EN_DS_HEDM-55xx_2014-11-20-952416.pdf) can be used with a stepper motor semicircular shaft (with the shape like in [this picture](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/mechanical-rotary-encoders/6234136/))?
[image]

Comment: Your "this picture" link leads to an error page.

Comment: @Felthry The link works for me.

Comment: The link led me to a redirection page where I had to click another link to get to the final page.

Comment: @CharlesCowie I've modified the link.

Answer (score 1):

The drawing for the encoder shows a hex wrench for tightening a set screw. That indicates it is intended to accept a flatted shaft like the one shown in the other link. The drawing for the HED-5500 encoder should show that more clearly and should show the diameter of the hole. Without knowing the diameter of the hole you can not determine if the motor shaft will fit.

Comment: The shaft is 8mm so I will use the HEDS-5500#A13, with a 8 mm hole.

Comment: I see that there is a table indicating the accepted shaft diameters. There is also information about tapped holes required in the face of the end of the motor.

Answer (score 1):

It's not semi-circular but rather "has a flat" and as already mentioned the indicated encoder is designed to be screw tightened on a shaft. So mechanically it should work provided the set screw has the appropriate depth limit required.

However, whether that means the encoder will work is undefined. The encoder pulse positions may not line up with the stepper angles as you desire.

Some adjustment of the encoder body angle to motor body angle may be required.